# image is not loading in iphone

Tags: ios, codenameone

I have created own listmodel and  override its methods and image is displaying in android but in iphone it displays image first time and when back and return to the page then it dispays only white screen , how to solve it?

```
@Override
public Image getItemAt(final int index) {
    if (images[index] == null) {
        String imageName = "image_" + urls.get(index).hashCode();
        if (Storage.getInstance().exists(imageName)) {
            InputStream is;
            try {

                is = Storage.getInstance().createInputStream(imageName);
                EncodedImage i = EncodedImage.create(is, is.available());
                images[index] = i;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            images[index] = defaultImage;
            Util.downloadUrlToStorageInBackground(urls.get(index), imageName, (e) -> {
                try {
                    images[index] = EncodedImage.create(Storage.getInstance().createInputStream(imageName));
                    listeners.fireDataChangeEvent(index, DataChangedListener.CHANGED);
                } catch (IOException err) {
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    return images[index];
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Did you debug this with a breakpoint what line misbehaves? How are you showing the model? Thru an ImageViewer or a List?

Comment: there is no error in emulator and android devices and it problems in iphone only

Comment: how to view storage files in xcode emulator and how to clear storage file in xcode emulator ?

Comment: Uninstalling the app removes the storage. There is a storage viewer here which you can integrate into your app for debugging: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html#_storage

Comment: I have checked the file storage and check the files available or not.
And its available but the image is not displaying . I have used this code to display image from storage. 
is = Storage.getInstance().createInputStream(imageName);
                EncodedImage i = EncodedImage.create(is, is.available());
                images[index] = i;

Comment: `EncodedImage i = EncodedImage.create(is, is.available());` is incorrect. Use  EncodedImage i = EncodedImage.create(is); or get the length from storage. `available()` doesn't always return the right value.

Comment: I have alos EncodedImage i = EncodedImage.create(is);  but not working

how can its length can be taken using storage ?

Comment: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Storage.html#entrySize-java.lang.String- Try isolating what isn't working. If the download resulted in corrupt files, the EncodedImage loading etc.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to return `null` for missing images which might be a problem. You need to return placeholder values and replace them later.